# Push Notification service for android app not published on google play

Tags: android, push-notification, google-play, publish

We have an Android app, which is not published on google play, only released on our own website to download the apk.

Recently we want to include google cloud service to enable push notification, and we are wondering if it is possible to do that for unpublished app?

Thanks

Comment: You can still use GCM/FCM, absolutely for free, if your app is not published to Google Play. No need to use a paid service if your use case is simple. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very possible.

Either use a service such as Urban Airship or...

1. Go into your developer's console and enable Google Cloud Messaging
2. Download the Google Play Services library.
3. Using the library, register the device.
4. After registration, you will receive a token unique to the device. Use that token to send an Http request to google's servers and google will handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With Google Play Services, the app will have push notification no matter if it is published on google play, right?

Comment: It will have it enabled. You must follow steps 2-4 to actually send the push to the device.