# JavaScript - Button Click to send data remotely

Tags: javascript, java, android

I have a list of company tablets (Android) that are located all around the United States. I would like to be able to select one from a list, compose a message, then be able to send the message to the selected device. Some locations have multiple tablets on the same network, in which i'd like to send to all of them at once if possible.

Is it possible to send data over the internet via JavaScript to an android device, or a list of devices? If so, how can this be done? Is there a certain term for what I am trying to do so I may google this for better results?

I apologize for my lack of knowledge and terms.

Comment: You can send any data you want to any remote device using AJAX. However, the remote device (be it an apple, android, windows or linux) has to either have an app installed to receive the data and display it to the user OR simply open a webpage that receives the data and display the data...

Comment: Is it possible to send data over the internet via JavaScript to an android device --- by this, do you mean push notification?

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar A push notification, that sounds correct. Do you know if I can push to all devices within a defined network? I do not want to push to all devices within the United States. This also means that I would have to create a service to listen for the push. I have no idea how to do that. Should I edit my question to ask this question instead?

Comment: @FoxDonut in order to listen to a push notification, you need an app. and the app must be installed the device. let's say the first time user will open the app, it will register the device along with the career name and other information you need in backend. later you can use those data to send push notification

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar Thank you for the information, I believe I can get started on researching further in depth due to your help. I very much appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two options you have:

### 1. Use websockets to send messages to active devices

In your backend system (you need one) keep a list of active connections. In your webpage, display the connections. Select one, and in an input field type a message. Send this message to the backend, e.g. form post, and send this message to the corresponding connection. In your active device, have an app working that listens to the socket and displays the message.

### 2. Use Push notifications

You can easily send push notifications to android devices. However, you need a working app on a device before you can send it pushnotifications. Firstly, the app needs to register itself at GooglePlayServices, there's a ton of tutorials on this. Then this will give the app a deviceId, which it needs to send to your backend. In your backend you keep track of all deviceIds in your database.
The same principle holds for alternative 1: display the deviceId's in your listbox, and send it together with a message to your backend.
In the backend send a push notification to the device. There's also a ton of tutorials on how to do that (you need to set up a project in Google to get an API key, which is really easy).

There are probably other alternatives, but these two are the most easy I'm sure.

Also, in order to group send notifications, group devices by their external IP. Make the devices register themselves to your backend so you have their external IP, then group them by that in your database. In the frontend now select an IP instead of a device.

**EDIT by FoxDonut (Asker)**
I also asked, in the comments below, if it is possible to use push notifications without uploading my application into the Google Play Store. The answer is Yes. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258798/push-notification-service-for-android-app-not-published-on-google-play) post for clarity.

Comment: My application is a security application that can only be used by locations that have purchased our entire system. Thus, I cannot upload my software to the Google Play Store. Can I still register my app with GooglePlayServices without uploading the software?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can yea. Set up a project in Google developer dashboard or whatever it's called. Then look up how to register an android device to Google Play Services. When you send a push notification to a device, it goes to Googles messaging service that finds your device. GooglePlayServices listens for these notifications, and pipes it to your app based on the devicetoken

Comment: I believe I have the information I need to get started on research. Thank you very much for your contribution!